# SEC7111 HTTP security compromised by Microsoft Edge extension

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I implemented an edge extension where my popup has embedded iframe while loading the popup, it throws an error i.e.

SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by ms-browser-extension://SecureInput_55A39EC1FD424BE88AD67FFE91F90A63/pages/notification.html

SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by ms-browser-extension://SecureInput_55A39EC1FD424BE88AD67FFE91F90A63/scripts/lib/underscore-min.js

How to fix these issues?

Comment: Without more details about what the extension does, it's not possible to answer.

Comment: When end user clicks on extension icon in edge browser, extension pops out one html page popup window, where html page has iframe embedded with it, so while loading that html page it throws this exception in console while debugging the extension content script.

Answer (score 0):

We're aware of this issue and are tracking it publicly: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8748330/

From what we've seen in our tests, however, these exceptions are merely cosmetic (i.e. we're displaying the message, but do not actually prevent the loading of any resources).

If you are actually seeing resources being blocked, please let me know, as this is something we are not aware of.